# How to implement Blacklist in java

Tags: java

I would like to implement a method `isInBlackList(String element)`, which return true, if  `element` is founded in the blacklist. I have the following code:

```
public boolean isInBlackList(String element) {
        Set<String> blackList = new HashSet<String>();
        blackList.add("element1");
        blackList.add("element2");
        ...
        .....
        blackList.add("element20");

        return blackList.contains(element);
    }
```

What is bothering me is that I have to write `add()` method 20 times. Any better idea? it does not have to be implemented with `Set`.

Comment: Why are you adding, what appears to be, random elements to your blacklist when checking if an element is in the blacklist?

Comment: Well, is there better way to initial the blacklist with my 20 Elements?

Comment: I'm guessing you only want to initialize it once

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ that is right

Comment: Then look at my first comment :p

Comment: You're initialising 20 elements to your set that will only be in scope of that method. Do as @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ said, make this set a field of the class as it appears your class will be modifying/using this set.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you go through a tutorial that deals with scopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is the following:

```
final List<String> blackList = Arrays.asList("element1", "element2", "element3");
```

As you can see, that's... really minimalist, and still works :)

Comment: You missed the part about moving it outside of the method

Answer (score 3):

You may try like this:

```
Set<String> blackList = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("element1", "element2", "element3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `blacklist` a field of your class and initialize it with :

```
Set<String> blackList = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("element1", ...));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
Set<String> blackList = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test12 ss = new Test12();
        ss.populateBlackList();  // if the blacklist is fixed means you can call this in constructor 
        System.out.println(ss.isInBlackList("element1"));
    }

    private void populateBlackList() // make it as an seperate method dont populate at all time
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            blackList.add("element" + i);
        }
    }

    public boolean isInBlackList(String element) //finding the blackList
    {
        return blackList.contains(element);
    }
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. By my understanding, the "element 1", "element 2" etc. was just an example

Answer (score 0):

1. declare blackList as a member variable and initialize it in constructor.
2. just use a for loop to add the elements

   for( int i = 1; i<=20; i++){

   ```
   string s = "element"+i;
       blackList.add(s);
   }
   ```